# Can the identity $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}=\ln{a}$ be proven rigorously from the Power Rule for Integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

For any $a>0$, we know that the derivative of the function $f(x)=a^x$ at $x=0$ is equal to $\ln{a}$. Using the definition of the derivative, this fact may be expressed as the limit equation
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}=\ln{a}.$$
Let us suppose that we use the definition of $\ln$ as the antiderivative of $y=x^{-1}$ satisfying the initial condition $\ln(1)=0$ (in other words, as the signed area under the graph of $y=x^{-1}$ starting from $x=1$).

Then, it seems like I can prove the above limit equation by applying the Power Rule of Integration in the limit as the power approaches $-1$.

We know by the Power Rule that the signed area under the graph of $y=x^n$ from $x=1$ to $x=a$ is given by
$$\int_{x=1}^{x=a}x^n \ dx=\frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{1^{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{n+1}.$$
Since $y=x^n$ is continuous with respect to $n$, we know that $x^n\to x^{-1}$ as $n\to -1$.

Thus, the signed area under the graph of $y=x^n$ from $x=1$ to $x=a$ should approach the signed area under the graph of $y=x^{-1}$ from $x=1$ to $x=a$ in the limit $n\to -1$.

We know that the signed area under the graph of $y=x^{-1}$ from $x=1$ to $x=a$ is by definition equal to $\ln{a}$, and we found that the area under the graph of $y=x^n$ from $x=1$ to $x=a$ is equal to $\displaystyle\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$.

Thus, it follows that
$$\lim_{n\to -1}\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{n+1}=\ln{a},$$
which one recognizes as precisely the same limit equation I mentioned at the beginning.

Although the above proof seems reasonable, I am not sure whether it can be made rigorous (or whether it has any fundamental flaw). I have tried searching in calculus textbooks and online, but I have yet to find a worked-out proof that uses the reasoning I used above. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this argument can easily be made rigorous. For $a > 1$,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to -1} \left|\frac{a^{n+1} - 1}{n+1} - \ln(a) \right| &= \lim_{n \to -1} \left| \int_1^a x^n - x^{-1} dx \right| \\
 & \leq \lim_{n \to -1} \int_1^a |x^n - x^{-1}| dx \\
 & \leq \lim_{n \to -1} (a-1) |a^n - a^{-1}| \\
 & = 0, \
\end{align*}

since $f(x) = a^x$ is continuous at $x = -1$, and $g_n(x) = |x^n - x^{-1}|$ is an increasing function on $[1, a]$ for all $n < 0$. A similar argument works for $0 < a < 1$.